# How to alter the style of a singe prop of a component. React Native

Tags: react-native, expo, components, styles, react-props

Well, i'm importing a header component where I build my title, subtitle, and top buttons.
I want to import the title, but with a small change on its style, just changing the color to yellow.

How could I change just the color style of title, without touching the other props, or making a new prop in the component?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCDpR.png

PS: My first post, I don't know how to paste the img pretty well.

this is the code:

```
<SimpleHeader                 
           style={styles.header}
           title='¡Hola Celia!' /* Yellow color*/
           subtitle='¿Qué te lavamos hoy?'
 />
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not gonna be able to be exact unless you share the SimpleHeader component but this logic should work for you:

1. In the SimpleHeader component, add a prop called titleColor and pass it to the text:

   <Text title style={[styles.title, {color:props.titleColor}]}>{title}
2. Pass that extra titleColor prop from the main component:

   <SimpleHeader
   style={styles.header}
   title='¡Hola Celia!' /* Yellow color*/
   subtitle='¿Qué te lavamos hoy?'
   titleColor='yellow'
   />

Comment: I only whant to change the prop "title" not adding yellow to the whole SimpleHeader.

Comment: Can you share the code for the SimpleHeader component?

Comment: The whole component is a bit big, I'll write the prop title:`
```
{title ? (
                    <View>
                        <Text title style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
                    </View>
                ) : null}
```

Comment: Check the edited answer.